# What kind of a design is this?

Tags: vector, logo

I'd like to know if these kinds of logos are categorized or labeled as something.

[image]

[image]

[image]

One thing I noticed is that they all make you look at the negative space.

E: I also noticed that they all connect to the background to use the negative space to make the actual logo.

Comment: Not *everything* has a *specific* name. Those are simply one color logos.

Comment: They could be considered 'cut out logo's' or 'negative space logo's'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called 'negative space logos'.

Here are some examples:

- [Design Shack](http://designshack.net/articles/inspiration/80-clever-negative-space-logo-designs/)
- [Bored Panda](http://www.boredpanda.com/negative-space-logos/)
- [CSS Design Awards](http://www.cssdesignawards.com/articles/60-negative-space-logos-for-creative-thinkers/53/)

I call them negative silhouettes. The classic is the two face/a vase:

[Negative Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_space)